# How can I update a 'long' datatype in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Probably about 300K rows. Using SQL and/or PL/SQL.

Would it be best to copy/convert into an interim format in a temporary table, work on it and then import it back in?

The updated data would need to remain as a 'long' datatype because we don't have the resources (or inclination) to fix the DB.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the LONG data type doesn't really work with SQL and PL/SQL...  Any chance that all your data is less than 32k in length?  That would make life much easier.

Are you strictly limited to SQL and/or PL/SQL?  Or is that just a preference?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but suspect the data would be less than 32K. SQL and/or PL/SQL are a preference, but I'm open to any ideas. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here 4 ways are explained how to convert the long column to a clob. Online redefinition is possible.

http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-convert-long-data-type-to-lob.html

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't an option. We don't have the source to alter the app that uses the DB.